# When should I bother about RandomGenerator.isDeprecated()?

Tags: java, random

In my Java 17 code I came across the method `new Random().isDeprecated()` (which returns a `boolean`) and was wondering how it should be used from a developer perspective.

Can I easily ignore it while doing non-security and non-cryptography related stuff with `Random`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ignore it.

The standard random number generators (`SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()` and `new Random()`) won't be deprecated.

Whenever you call e.g. `rnd.nextInt()`, that `rnd` didn't fall out of the sky. Either [A] you made it, or [B] it was provided to you e.g. as a parameter or set in the constructor of the class that contains the call to `.nextInt()`. Given that the caller decided to hand you a deprecated algorithm, roll with it. They evidently wanted it that way.

Where it could potentially be useful is something exotic like this:

As a setting in a file or in some settings dialog, you allow the user of your application to pick the RNG algorithm. You use this to create an instance of Random (instead of `new Random()`) and would like to let the user know if they picked a deprecated algorithm, e.g. by adding a warning icon (yellow triangle with an exclamation mark for example) and the text: `"CAREFUL: You have chosen a deprecated RNG algorithm. You may want to choose a different one, or pick the default instead"`.

*Then* `isDeprecated()` can help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation note, within the JavaDoc.

*[RandomGenerator#isDeprecated (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#isDeprecated())*.

> *"**Implementation Note:***
>
> *Random number generator algorithms evolve over time; new algorithms will be introduced and old algorithms will lose standing. If an older algorithm is deemed unsuitable for continued use, it will be marked as deprecated to indicate that it may be removed at some point in the future."*

And you mention,

> *"... and was wondering how it should be used from a developer perspective. ..."*

So, I guess they are implying that is not a *deprecation* in the classical sense.
It's just the annotation they will use when the algorithm has become hyperbolic.

> *... Can I easily ignore it while doing non-security and non-cryptography related stuff with `Random`?"*

The method is in regard to when utilizing a specific algorithm.

Consider the following; from the *java.util.random* JavaDoc.

*[java.util.random (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/package-summary.html)*.

> *"... one can choose a specific implementation by giving the name of a generator algorithm to the static method RandomGenerator.of(java.lang.String), in which case the no-arguments constructor for that implementation is used:*
>
> *RandomGenerator g = RandomGenerator.of("L64X128MixRandom"); ..."*

This is where it may be logical to implement the *isDeprecated* method in your code, to possibly alert you.

```java
assert !g.isDeprecated;
```